# Send synchronized audio and video data over the network

Tags: c#, video-streaming, directshow, audio-streaming, naudio

I have separately sent  Audio and Video over the network but i want to send synchronized audio video data over the network.if any one could me to the solution it would be greatly appreciated.
p.s: i am using Naudio for audio and DirectShow for video.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the first point you have to make sure is that you are generating the RTCP packets at some fixed interval of time. RTCP maps the rtp timestamps with NTP. And this is required at the client end for syncing audio and video.